# How Interpreter consumes Bytecodes and executes it

Tags: python, interpreter, bytecode

I am intending to understand how Interpreter consumes Bytecodes and executes it. If we take Python for example, it generates bytecodes and then interprets it. I an interested in knowing how does the interpreter consumes the bytecode instruction set and executes them.

For example:

```
>>> def test():
...  print " hello"
... 
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (' hello')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now, how would I interpret this bytecode instructions and execute it ?

Answer (score 2):

Python uses an evaluation loop to execute the bytecode. See [`ceval.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c) for the implementation (in C).

If you wanted to interpret the byte code instructions yourself from Python, you'd need an intimate knowledge of what each instruction is supposed to do and where to find the data structures that govern their execution. `LOAD_CONST 1` here, for example, loads the constant at index 1 from the code object that is attached to the function and puts it on the stack, and `PRINT_ITEM` takes the top stack value, turns it into a string and writes it to `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Actually I just want to learn on how to create an interpreter to execute bytecode instructions. It may not be confined to python alone. Is there any resource , which could help me get on with it ?

Comment: @Rahul: That is *way* too broad a subject to cover here, nor am I aware of any resources or tutorials.